# How to downgrade python 3.7 to 3.6 in Anaconda for use with tensorflow?

Tags: conda

I think python 3.7 still has issues with tensorflow, even tensorflow2.

So I am downgrading python 3.7 to 3.6.  I am using conda install python=3.6. And it failed, pls see below error message.  Is it due to company firewall policy? Basically, I cannnot use any conda command. Using pip is fine. Any suggestion? Thanks.

```
(base) C:\Users>conda install python=3.6
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'tls_process_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')])")))'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a connection issue and is not specific to trying to downgrade the pyhton version

> Is it due to company firewall policy

Likely you might need to configure a proxy or similar

> `please file
>   a support request with your network engineering team`

The error says it all. Since this is a network issue in your company, you should talk to your IT department on how to configure properly

Comment: Thanks Flying Teller. I solved this HTTP error by running conda config --set ssl_verify false